# How to get the text content of a src script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script like this:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader" src="./Shaders/Phong/vertex_shader"> </script>
```

How do I get it's text? I tried:

```
console.log($("#vertexShader").text());
```

But I always get an empty string, not the string contained in the file. How do I get the file content?

Comment: The missing "#" was only a copy paste error, it is not working anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to issue a ajax query :

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            var scriptContent = httpRequest.responseText;
            console.log(scriptContent);
        }
    }
};
httpRequest.open('GET', document.getElementById('vertexShader').src);
httpRequest.send();
```

Avoid jQuery ajax functions, as they automatically execute scripts.

Comment: Do I have to link a script beyond jquery? Because I still get an empty string.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I edited with a new version (not using jQuery). I tested it and it works.

Comment: Of course this script must me executed when the DOM is ready, so that the element is found.

Comment: Note: to make it work I had to remove the "if (httpRequest.status === 200)", the status was always zero.

Comment: That's not normal. You might have a problem on the server.

Comment: What if I don't have a server at all? I just need javascript, with no server side scripts.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#vertexShader").Text()` will get you nothing, because the script is loaded remotely :)

If you want to get the script contents you can do `var url=$("#vertexShader").attr('src');` which will get you the url for the script. Now you can load it with

```
var response;

$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: url,
        success:function(data){
            response=data;
        }
    });
```

Which would get you the script contents into the response variable

Comment: This has the side effect that it executes the script.

Comment: It does? Why, I'm just getting it as the ajax response... am I not?

Comment: Try it by putting a console.log in your script.

Answer (score -1):

In CSS selectors, to get an element with an **id** you must prefix it with **#**. Like

```
#vertexShader
```

So it becomes

```
$('#vertexShader')
```

Comment: It still won't get the external script's contents because the tag itself is empty.

Comment: If the tag is empty it may mean that DOM is not yet ready. Wrap your script inside $(document).ready(function() {your code here });